# kubectl: The connection to the server XXX.XXX.XXXXXX was refused

Tags: firewall, docker, port-forwarding, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I am trying to connect to kubernetes master (cluster) in Google Cloud Engine.

The error that always I get when the *kubectl* try to access to kubernetes master is:

> The connection to the server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX was refused - did you
>   specify the right host or port?

For example:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

As far I check the client is using same version that the server (version 1.5.2). But for some weird reason, it is refusing to connect.

```
$ gcloud beta container get-server-config
Fetching server config for europe-west1-c
defaultClusterVersion: 1.5.2
defaultImageType: GCI
validImageTypes:
- CONTAINER_VM
- GCI
validMasterVersions:
- 1.5.2
- 1.4.8
validNodeVersions:
- 1.5.2
- 1.5.1
- 1.4.8
- 1.4.7
- 1.4.6
- 1.3.10
- 1.2.7
```

In kubernetes master cluster (server version) I get the following error:

```
# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I follow this steps for the kubernetes cluster master creation:

```
export APP_NAME=brand-project
export GOOGLE_CONTAINER_NAME=b.gcr.io/brand/project
gcloud container clusters create $APP_NAME --zone europe-west1-c --machine-type g1-small --num-nodes 1
```

I get and I set perfectly the credentials:

```
gcloud config set container/cluster $APP_NAME
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $APP_NAME
gcloud auth application-default login
```

The description is good:

```
gcloud container clusters describe $APP_NAME
```

The google config too:

```
gcloud config list
```

The context seem legit too in:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

Even I can ssh to kubernetes master cluster, but only SSH, no HTTP or HTTPS or for example run properly kubectl.

I read too in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/master-node-communication/):

> Google Container Engine uses SSH tunnels to protect the Master ->
>   Cluster communication paths. In this configuration, the apiserver
>   initiates an SSH tunnel to each node in the cluster (connecting to the
>   ssh server listening on port 22) and passes all traffic destined for a
>   kubelet, node, pod, or service through the tunnel. This tunnel ensures
>   that the traffic is not exposed outside of the private GCE network in
>   which the cluster is running.

So I don't know how to open the 8000 port in Kubernetes Cluster mastter for allow the connection (and opening all the ports in firewall in Google Cloud Engine seems not work too).

I am out of ideas, and I mostly search all google related entries. So I don't have idea how to solve to connect with the server or what I am doing wrong in the process. Any help is very appreciated!

EDIT:

After check "[Container Registry Deprecation Notices](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/deprecation-notices)" the container location was updated to eu.gcr.io instead b.gcr.io according to:

> On February 28th, 2017, the use of “bring your own bucket” registries
>   such as b.gcr.io and bucket.gcr.io is considered deprecated. After
>   that date, Container Registry will no longer serve any container
>   images that you had in those buckets.

But the issue still persist.

Comment: what does `kubectl get services` return?

Comment: Exactly the same error The connection to the server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX was refused - did you specify the right host or port?. I see all the proces in other machine and it works, so I am thinking that it some with this laptop as version. It seems to fail just in the auth refusing to connect and .json auth file seems legit

Comment: do you have a `~/.kube/config`?

Comment: I just found the real issue, I post it as answer, but thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolving my own answer. It seems that the real problem was access and connecting to accounts.google.com via DNS. After I check that I have ping:

```
$ ping accounts.google.com
PING accounts.google.com (216.58.201.141) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mad06s25-in-f13.1e100.net (216.58.201.141): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=21.9 ms
64 bytes from mad06s25-in-f13.1e100.net (216.58.201.141): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from mad06s25-in-f13.1e100.net (216.58.201.141): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=20.4 ms
^C
--- accounts.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.070/20.468/21.914/1.173 ms
```

And stracing all the opened files during the command:

```
$ strace -eopenat kubectl version
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/stat", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/hostname", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/shakaran/.kube/config", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/shakaran/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/hostname", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
The connection to the server 104.155.120.114 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I try to figure out the opened connections:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status | cat
Global
         DNS Servers: 127.0.1.1
                      8.8.8.8
                      8.8.4.4
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 10 (vboxnet3)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes

Link 9 (vboxnet2)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes

Link 8 (vboxnet1)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes

Link 7 (vboxnet0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes

Link 6 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes

Link 5 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes

Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
                      8.8.4.4

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
```

I just discover that I have it the openvpn with tun0 enabled (blocking the connection to accounts.google.com), after I run the disable of the interface:

```
sudo ifconfig tun0 down
```

I get perfectly:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:52:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
So sorry for all the noise. But probably it is a good idea add this in FAQ's or so for warning the users about VPNs
```

So the issue was mostly a refused connection. It could be useful the issue [#41975 in kubernetes project](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41975#issuecomment-282860715) for debug with the -v=4 like:

```
$ kubectl version -v=4
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
I0224 11:32:36.914299   30751 helpers.go:221] Connection error: Get https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: dial tcp: lookup accounts.google.com on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:46403->127.0.1.1:53: read: connection refused
F0224 11:32:36.914378   30751 helpers.go:116] The connection to the server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```